# How to retrieve a specific value from MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, get, sql-update

I am new to PHP and I would like some inputs on this little script.  Everything seems to work but I need to know how to retrieve the "id" of the message that is modified.

```
<?php
function updatemyinfos() {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
**$id=**
$sql="UPDATE table1 SET message = '$_POST[message]' WHERE id ='$id'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo '<p>Message modifié</p>';
mysqli_close($con);
}

if(isset($_POST['updatemessage']))
{
    updatemyinfos();
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<textarea style="resize:none" cols="1" rows="1" name="message"id="textbox">'.$row['message'].'</textarea>           
<input type="submit" value="Soumettre" name="updatemessage" id="updatemessage">
</form>
```

EDIT : I tried this.. I don't get any error message but the datebase does not update.  But I get the "echo '

Message modifié

"

```
<?php
function updatemyinfos($id) {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","TP1AlexandreBouletCouture");
                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                  {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                  }



                $sql="UPDATE table1 SET message = '$_POST[message]' WHERE id ='$id'";




                if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
                  {
                  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                  }
                echo '<p>Message modifié</p>';


                mysqli_close($con);
            }

            if(isset($_POST['updatemessage']))
            {
            updatemyinfos($_POST['updatemessage']);
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change these lines

```
if(isset($_POST['updatemessage']))
{
updatemyinfos();
}
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['updatemessage']))
{
updatemyinfos($_POST['updatemessage']);
}
```

and this

```
function updatemyinfos()
```

to

```
function updatemyinfos($id)
```

Comment: I don't get any error message but my database does not update when I submit the form. But I do get the echo '<p>Message modifié</p>';

Comment: shouldn;t this $_POST[message] be $_POST['message']

Answer (score 0):

Hi try following query,

```
    $sql1 = "Select id from table where message = '$_POST[message]'";
```